# Is there an easier way to check if password and repeated password match in a form?

Tags: html, angular

In my form I have two text fields in which user should write his new password and repeat that password.

I've tried a lot of different things with *ngIf, and now I'm pretty confused with how it works. I've tried calling a function that compares strings and returns true or false, but that didn't work either.

```
<mat-card>
  <form (submit)="onSubmit(form)" #form="ngForm">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          New password:
        </td>
        <td>
          <mat-form-field>
            <input
              matInput
              type="password"
              name="newPsw"
              ngModel
              required
              #newPsw="ngModel"/>
            <mat-error *ngIf="newPsw.invalid"
              >Required field!</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Repeat new password:
        </td>
        <td>
          <mat-form-field>
            <input
              matInput
              type="password"
              name="newPswRepeated"
              ngModel
              required
              #newPswRepeated="ngModel"
            />
            <mat-error *ngIf="newPswRepeated.value!==newPsw.value">Passwords don't match!</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">
            Sign Up
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</mat-card>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a validator on a FormGroup for such a comparison:

```
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

export const equivalentValidator = (firstControlName: string, secondControlName: string) => {

  return (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
    const firstControl = formGroup.get(firstControlName);
    const secondControl = formGroup.get(secondControlName);

    if (firstControl.value !== secondControl.value) {
      return secondControl.setErrors({ notEqual: true });
    }
  }

}
```

In your component, create a FormGroup, assigning the validator to the group itself:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor (
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      newPsw: [
        '', [ Validators.required, ]
      ],
      newPswRepeated: [
        '', [ Validators.required, ]
      ]
    }, {
      validator: equivalentValidator('newPsw', 'newPswRepeated'),
    });

  }

}
```

Now the `newPswRepeated` field will have an error of `notEqual` you can react to if the fields don't have the same value.

```
<mat-error *ngIf="newPswRepeated.errors.notEqual">Passwords don't match!</mat-error>
```

You'll need to modify your form to be a reactive form to get the correct binding of values. See the [Reactive Forms docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) for more information. I think you'll find reactive forms will give you a lot tighter control compared to the template-driven syntax.

Comment: Thank you! Just out of curiosity though, could you explain why my way doesn't work?

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing more of the component code, but my guess is that the data binding between the two fields is out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom Validator like below to validate your password confirmation.

```
this.registerForm = this._formBuilder.group({
   email          : ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
   password       : ['', Validators.required],
   passwordConfirm: ['', [Validators.required, confirmPasswordValidator]]
});
```

## The validator

```
export const confirmPasswordValidator: ValidatorFn = (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {

    if ( !control.parent || !control )
    {
        return null;
    }

    const password = control.parent.get('password');
    const passwordConfirm = control.parent.get('passwordConfirm');

    if ( !password || !passwordConfirm )
    {
        return null;
    }

    if ( passwordConfirm.value === '' )
    {
        return null;
    }

    if ( password.value === passwordConfirm.value )
    {
        return null;
    }

    return {passwordsNotMatching: true};
};
```

You can do any type of validation by using a custom validator in Angular form. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-validation for Custom validation

> this.setPasswordForm = new FormGroup({
>               password:  new FormControl('', Validators.required);,
>               copassword: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, CustomValidators.equalTo(password)]);,
>           });